# Create VM from existing Linux System

Tags: linux, windows, virtual-machine, ubuntu-14.04, virtualbox

I just create a new Virtual Machine on a Windows 7 host with Ubuntu 14.04. 
Beforehand, I created an iso-image of an Ubuntu - PC using

```
dd if=/dev/sda | pv > /path/to/image.iso
```

I also tried

```
dd if=/dev/sda of=/path/to/image.iso
```

Then I added the image to the vm like described in the first answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/413594/what-does-no-bootable-medium-found-mean-in-a-virtual-box) but everytime I want to start the vm it returns

```
Fatal: No bootable medium found. System halted!
```

I also changed the UUIDs in the /etc/fstab to something like /dev/sda1, uncommented "GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true" in /etc/default/grub then ran update-grub and deleted everthing after the first comment in /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-net.rules

I'm writing the iso-image onto an external hard drive which is NTFS formatted. I'm not sure if that's the problem or am I missing something else?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Try running `file yourImage.iso` under Linux to see if it says it is bootable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An ISO is a structured image, and is not a raw read of bytes from a hard drive: one (generally) can't get an ISO just by using `dd`.  You will need to convert your raw image (what you are currently calling `image.iso`) to a VirtualBox format.  From the command line, this is fairly simple:

```
$ vboxmanage convertfromraw
Usage:

VBoxManage convertfromraw   <filename> <outputfile>
                            [--format VDI|VMDK|VHD]
                            [--variant Standard,Fixed,Split2G,Stream,ESX]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]
VBoxManage convertfromraw   stdin <outputfile> <bytes>
                            [--format VDI|VMDK|VHD]
                            [--variant Standard,Fixed,Split2G,Stream,ESX]
                            [--uuid <uuid>]
```

And turning that into something useful for you directly:

```
$ vboxmanage convertfromraw image.iso image.vdi --format VDI
```

Then, change out `image.iso` in your virtual machine's configuration with `image.vdi` and you *should* be good to go.

And to be clear, since presumably your previous installation was *to* a hard drive, you should make sure `image.vdi` is connected as a hard drive, and not another storage type.